# Local user's ID set as system user's ID

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, users

I have a to create local user for my web dev, so he will be able to restart Apache, run tomcat, have access to web root files, etc.

So far, I have been dealing with such thing by setting his uid as Apache uid.

Is it considered safe?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the kind of thing I've seen done in years.  Just give him access to run specific commands using sudo and keep the accounts as standard user accounts.